# Message queues- how do I know who I am?

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery, nose

I have a Flask application that uses Nose to discover and run a series of tests in a particular directory.  The tests take a long time to run, so I want to report the progress to the user as things are happening.

I use Celery to create a task that runs the test so I can return immediately and start displaying a results page.  Now I need to start reporting results.  I'm thinking in the test that I can just put a message on the queue that says 'I've completed step N'.

I know that Celery has task context I could use to determine which queue to write to, but the test isn't part of the task, it's a function that's called from the task.  I also can't use a flask session, because that context is gone when the test run is moved to a task.

I have seen several ways to do data driven nose tests, such as test generators or nose-testconfig, but that doesn't meet the requirement that the message queue name will be dynamic and there may be several threads running the same test.

**So, my question is:**  How do I tell the test that it corresponds to a particular celery task, ie: the one that started the test, so I can report it's status on the correct message queue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not use Celery and so I'm everything but good at it. However, I think you could overwrite `nose.core.TestProgram.runTests` and make it asynchronous with Celery. [Original implementation](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/core.py#L185). I admit that's not very useful.

Comment: How are you invoking the tests? You say they're "a function that's called from the task", but what does that mean? Are you calling the nose process? Is it just a normal Python function call? In the first case, maybe an environment variable would suffice. In the second one, you can use a global data structure, like a singleton or a thread-local variable, that both parts will access.